# Who would have ever thought vs Who had ever thought

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

1. Who would have ever thought a kid raised on welfare would now become a millionaire ?
2. Who had ever thought a kid raised on welfare would now become a millionaire ?

What are the differences between these two questions in meaningf?

Comment: _Who would have thought [it]?_ is the usual way of saying that something that has happened is surprising. Sentence (2) is not idiomatic English.

Comment: @KateBunting In what way is the second sentence not idiomatic ?

Comment: It's just 'not what people say'.

Comment: #2 sounds like half a sentence to me, i.e. "There weren't many, who had ever thought..."

Comment: @DustInComp Why can't I say  i.e. "There weren't many, who would have ever thought..."  ?

Comment: @DustInComp's version is not a question. The standard version is a rhetorical question (one not expecting an answer) - "Who would have thought that X could happen?" meaning that nobody would, because it's so surprising.)

Comment: @KateBunting how about the second sentence ?

Comment: As I said in my original comment, it is not idiomatic - it's not a thing that people commonly say.

Comment: @KateBunting In what context will it become idiomatic and meaningful ?

Comment: In _no_ context - that's what I've been trying to tell you!